# In Hyperledger Fabric, can I determine the Asset Class in the transaction?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

quick question regarding hyperledger fabric transactions in JS.

Say, I have an abstract asset called HotBeverage:

```
 abstract asset HotBeverage identified by assetId {
  o String assetId
  o Double price
}
```

And from that abstract class, I create two more assets:

```
asset HotTea extends HotBeverage {
 o String teaType
}
```

and

```
asset HotCoffee extends HotBeverage {
 o String coffeeType
}
```

OK, fairly straight forward so far. Now say I want to create a transaction that adds 0.50 to the price of all HotBeverages. Transactions currently cannot accept abstract assets, so it means I need to create **two separate** transactions :'(

```
transaction changeTeaPrice {
  --> HotTea Tea
  o Double newPrice
}
```

And

```
transaction changeCoffeePrice {
  --> HotCoffee coffee
  o Double newPrice
}
```

I really want to **create just one transaction** that would work on all HotBeverages instead of implementing them individually. Can this be done?

Thanks!!

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to find out the AssetType in the chaincode? For example, I create a transaction with a generic asset, then in the chaincode, I can find out if that asset is hotCoffee or hotTea?

Comment: within a transaction you can use the following:  `asset.getType()` `asset.getFullyQualifiedType()`

Comment: Thanks @RThatcher. I found that just a couple of minutes ago!! Do you know where it is used in an example? When I try to implement it, which asset should be listed in the Transaction?

Comment: I solved this issue by creating a single transaction and passing to it a string with the fully qualified reference to the asset, rather than the full asset itself. Then in the transaction code, I was able to find that asset in the assetRegistry and implement my code accordingly.